# Querying data from sqlite database results filename?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, express

I have created an express app for my server side and I am using sqlite database. I am trying to display the data on the client side but rather than the data get displayed, it is displaying the file name.

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
       $.ajax({url: "/data", success: function(result){
           $("#div1").html(result);
           console.log(result);
       }});
   });
```

});

I am getting this, instead of JSON

```
Object {open: false, filename: "Test.sqlite.sqlite", mode: 65542}
```

Any suggestions??

Comment: where is dataType property of ajax function?

Comment: what /data will output when directly write URL in browser?

Comment: On terminal it shows an array of objects @uzaif

Comment: check it in postman google chrome extension?which kind object it return?

Comment: I tried on Postman and it's returning this "{
  "open": false,
  "filename": "Test.sqlite.sqlite",
  "mode": 65542
}"

Rather than the data inside this file. @uzaif

Comment: you have issue in server side not client side, fix the server side code it will work fine man?

Comment: @uzaif Thanks it worked somehow :)

Comment: is there sever side issue?

Comment: yeah, i forgot to render the response into index

Comment: okey great job man you find solution your self

Comment: Thanks for your help @uzaif

Answer (score 0):

By using JSON.stringify() function, you will get JSON string according below rewritten code.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/data", success: function (result) {
                    $("#div1").html(JSON.stringify(result));
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                }
            });
        });
    });
```